# How to I use Facebook Graph API to show me events I'm a host of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, koala

I'm using Facebook oauth and koala gems to create an app that helps with event management on the fly. I have successfully listed simple  information about myself, events I've been invited to, and people I'm friends with.

I understand that people and event objects have sibling relationships so you cannot find information of one in another aside for what events you've been invited to. So how do You list events that you're a host of?

Comment: make sure that you have permission: user_events, then try to read events as: @graph.get_connections("me", "events")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it. In User.rb after self.from_omniauth method:
:

```
def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)    
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
    logger.info e.to_s
    nil
end

  def api_call
    query = "Me?fields=picture.type(large),location,events.fields(name,location,end_time,privacy,updated_time,description,rsvp_status,venue,start_time,id,ticket_uri,picture.type(large),cover,owner,admins.fields(picture.type(large),name,location),attending.fields(picture.type(large),name,rsvp_status,first_name,last_name,email,location),maybe.fields(rsvp_status,picture.type(large),name,first_name,last_name,email,age_range,location)),friends.fields(cover,id,gender,location,username,email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large))"
  end

  def generate_user_events
    fb_call = facebook { |fb| fb.graph_call(api_call)}

    unless fb_call["events"].nil?
      events = fb_call["events"]["data"]
      events.each do |event|
        #All information from each event.
      end #/ each do |event|
    end #/ check to see if user has events
  end

end
```